# Debian package issue

Tags: package-management

I'm using Ubuntu Studio 15.10.

I want to install COMODO AntiVirus, which is a Debian package, but I can't find the Debian Packages Installer in the menu.

How can I install the package?

Comment: 32bit or 64bit ?

Answer (score 0):

- The DebPackage is located on there website [Here](https://www.comodo.com/home/download/download.php?prod=antivirus-for-linux&track=3646&key5sk1=5992b9088aff550cc4b0da6f1b4764fdc3a6bc22)

How to Install COMODO AntiVirus

**If your on 32bit run these commands**.

Download COMDO AntiVirus with the following command:

```
wget http://download.comodo.com/cavmgl/download/installs/1000/standalone/cav-linux_1.1.268025-1_i386.deb
```

Install COMDO with the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i cav-linux_1.1.268025-1_i386.deb
```

**If you are on 64bit run these commands**

Download COMDO AntiVirus with the following command:

```
wget http://download.comodo.com/cavmgl/download/installs/1000/standalone/cav-linux_1.1.268025-1_amd64.deb
```

Install COMDO with the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i cav-linux_1.1.268025-1_amd64.deb
```

oh if you want on-access scanning you need to 
Download Driver.tar

```
wget http://download945.mediafire.com/1do17tbb4pug/qpg2s4bimd1ig57/driver.tar
```

and then copy driver.tar to /opt/COMODO/

```
sudo cp driver.tar /opt/COMODO/
```

and then run (press q to agree to license )

```
sudo /opt/COMODO/post_setup.sh
```